# How difficulty increases to get the lucky hash in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hash, block-hash

Currently first 19 zeros are required in bitcoin block hash which has become very hard. How this zeros are being controlled to increase? If it is dynamic what are the factors which has influence to make hash matching difficult?

Comment: "Currently first 19 zeros are required" In hex. That's 76 zeros in binary which is a better way of saying it since the probability of finding a valid block after one attempt is 2^-76

Answer (score 0):

The Bitcoin algorithm is written to aim for 2,016 blocks being mined roughly every 2 weeks (which works out to ~1 block every 10 minutes on average). After every 2,016 blocks, the network will adjust the difficulty based on how long those previous 2,016 blocks took to mine: if it took longer than 2 weeks, the difficulty is decreased; if it took less than 2 weeks, the difficulty is increased.

For the exact calculations and more information: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty